# Filter pipes in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

[image]
I have 2 select fields,namely Category and Category Type. I need to filter the table based on these contents.
I have written pipe filter function as well.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <label style="font-size: 20px;color: #55595c;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif">Category</label>
      <ng-select [options]="category" [(ngModel)] = "filter.name" name="name" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="All" [allowClear]="true" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
      </ng-select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding" style="left:10%">
      <label style="font-size: 20px;color: #55595c;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif">Category Type</label>
      <ng-select [options]="catType" [(ngModel)] = "filter.cat_type" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="All" [allowClear]="true" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
      </ng-select>
    </div>
```

**component.ts:**

```
public filter: Categories = new Categories();
export class Categories {
  public _id:any;
  public name:string;
  public cat_type:string;
}
```

**Pipe.ts:**

```
export class Categories {
  public _id:any;
  public name:string;
  public cat_type:string;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'categoryfilter',
  pure: false
})


      export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Categories[], filter: Categories): Categories[] {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item: Categories) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  } 
  applyFilter(user: Categories, filter: Categories): boolean {
for (let field in filter) {
  if (typeof filter[field] == 'number') {
    console.log("working");
     if (user.name !== filter.name || user._id !== filter._id || user.cat_type !== filter.cat_type) { 
      return false;
    }
  }
}
  return true;
  }
}
```

I don't get any error, but the table is getting empty if i select item from the list.

Comment: try includes as i given in my answer might resolves your issue easily

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltxqou

Comment: instead of select just keep input box ...or li element ..or keep normal html base select

Comment: i just need cod which you are trying ..i will try to replicate same at my end ..will give me more clear picture

Comment: i see now , will try to get back to you asap

Comment: can you please provide data which is retunred by this call   .getAllCategories()..just json as i have to create data like that at my end

Comment: @PranayRana I had updated the json in css file please have a look

Comment: @PranayRana i have coded one more type, in that if i select the data, full table gets empty

Comment: it should be like this if (!filter) {
      return items;
    }

Comment: I updated my answer and provided code which is working for me ..hope that helps you

Comment: @PranayRana i wrote same way as you gave, but the table remains empty

Comment: that should work i cannot share at some website but its working for me , let me paste my html also you can try at your end same way

Comment: Is this HTML part correct? <ng-select [options]="category" [(ngModel)] = "filter.name" name="name" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="All" [allowClear]="true" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
      </ng-select>

Comment: i suggest you should try static fields first as i given in my answer then see working or not and afterwas apply it dynamically ...if you check my code I applied `&&` condition that is also you need to check , i.e. you are passing all values if not than i suggest just check based on id

Comment: ya sure, thank you i will check and update you

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your Category object have all properties at run time

or

```
 applyFilter(user: Categories, filter: Categories): boolean {
         if (user.name +"" !== filter.name +"" || user._id+"" !== filter._id+"" || user.cat_type+"" !== filter.cat_type+"") { 
             return false;
           }
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had corrected few things, jus a minute i will update the code

Comment: i have updated the code can you please have a look at it and help me

Comment: check you condition like user[field] !== filter[field] or user[field].toLowerCase()+"" !== filter[field].projectName.toLowerCase()+""

Comment: Is this correct? applyFilter(user: Categories, filter: Categories): boolean {
    for (let field in filter) {
      if (typeof filter[field] == 'number') {
        if (parseInt(user[field]) !== parseInt(filter[field])) {
          return false;
        }
        else if (user[field] !== filter[field]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

Comment: You can simple like if (user.name !== filter.name or user._id !== filter._id or user._cat !== filter._cat) { return false} remove loop

Comment: I am facing same issue even in that also

Comment: i have added code and checked, it is fully emptying contents in table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167225/discussion-between-birbal-singh-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input i tried this code and its working for me

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Categories } from './model';

@Pipe({
  name: 'categoryfilter',
  pure: false
})
export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Categories[], filter: Categories): Categories[] {
    if (!filter) {
      return items;
    }
    const filtered = items.filter(item => {
      if (filter._id === item._id && filter.cat_type === item.cat_type && filter.name === item.name) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    );
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

model.ts

```
export class Categories {
  public _id: any;
  public name: string;
  public cat_type: string;
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Categories } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  categories: Categories[];
  filter: Categories = { _id: 2, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz2' };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = [];
    this.categories.push({ _id: 1, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz1' });
    this.categories.push({ _id: 2, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz2' });
    this.categories.push({ _id: 3, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz3' });
    this.categories.push({ _id: 2, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz2' });
    this.categories.push({ _id: 2, cat_type: 'abc', name: 'xyz2' });
  }
}
```

component.html

```
  <table class="table adminTable">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let category of categories | categoryfilter: filter">
        <td>{{category.name}}</td>
        <td>{{category.cat_type}}</td>
        <td>
          test
            <!-- {{category.image}} -->
          <!-- <img class="cat-img" src="{{category.image}}"> -->
          <br>
          <p class="inputimg">
            <input type="file" name="{{category._id}}" id="{{category._id}}" class="inputfile" 
              style='display: none;' />
            <label for="{{category._id}}" class="img_change">Change</label>
          </p>
          <td>
            <button class="iconBtn first" >
              <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="iconBtn second" >
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

no change in html its will be same as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will check and update you

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - you just need to do like this in html `<tr *ngFor='let cat in Categories'>`..if you are getting data in that then suggest to put filter back and debugge that code till end i.e. till you receive something in items in filter code

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - thats what you have to debug ...by putting debugger, that must be some issue with the object filter that you are passing as pipe parameter

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - check the filter value after you get value in your items array.. I will be right back after 1 hr ...

Comment: ya checking, but not getting what to do.. i will keep trying

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - can you please share code of html and ts file where you are using this filter..

Comment: ya i will share now